# Streaming - how to incrementally process RDBMS updates and deletes events

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, flink-streaming, apache-beam

We are trying to re-engineer our current data pipeline and thinking if Streaming can be an alternative for data movement. RDBMS events involves INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on existing data as well as historic data. All this events can have keys to identify them uniquely. Correctness and completeness is important while processing these events and latency can be sacrificed at some extent. i.e. we need to process events in a micro-batch based on certain keys and we need to there is no more late event for that key (approximation, heuristic et are fine). Furthermore, this events are not ordered. i.e. key1, key2 data can arrive in conjunction. At some point all records of key1 will arrive and at other point all data of key2 will arrive. Problem is how to process the keyed data in a meaningful way. Again completeness is important. We can accumulate result in increments but it won't be useful until we have the complete data for given key.

One way I can think of is to use no-sql store to store this events using primary key as a row key and perform idempotent updates on no-sql store. But I think it also has to keep state of what keyed data changed and make it available for downstream users so they know what data changed. they can read that data now from no-sql store. But now problem is no-sql store is volatile so downstream may process inconsistent data.

Another approach is to not to rely on no-sql rather process data off the stream somehow. I am reading few concepts of stream processing like fixed-sliding window, session window, watermarks. but I can't see if any of these can solve the issue at hand. may be I need non aligned window based on data (keys) and 
some signal from publisher indicating completion of each batch of events?

Comment: Did you try any streaming engines like @apache-apex : http://apex.apache.org/ ?

Comment: I have not yet. Looking at spark streaming and google dataflow. I have updated my question to explain the use case. Do you know any specific concept that is been implemented by apex that can help my use case?

Answer (score 0):

I have put this project on aside but I went through quite a bit documentation on google dataflow, spark streaming and apache beam. Storm and Apex seemed too complicated at this point.

There are concepts like `watermarks` and `triggers` that looks promising to tell you when window is complete and when you should start processing. I can keep accumulating events until I receive watermark events for each stream that tell me to start processing. You may need to change your datasource or publisher of those events to send this "event completion" events. This may be just first part of puzzle. Once you have that custom window of events then you may need to go through those events and pull additional data from datastore (hbase, cassandra) before you start processing, or update/delete entries in datastore; also if you have further downstream users then you have to convey downstream what changes were complete in that custom window or upstream processing which may not be hard to access for any downstream since you already have that event. You may just need some kind of standard on those events to identify them across multiple consumers, downstreamers like customer id, transaction id, timeperiod etc.